# Who is this contact?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

When I'm on Whatsapp, there is this one contact that is always online when I'm checking status of contacts. However, a friend of mine has this exact same contact and on his phone the contact doesn't seem to always be online.

Who is this contact or rather how can this be explained?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, we hope you live up to your name! Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems too obvious, but is it

> yourself? You would of course be online every time you look, but not necessarily every time your friend looks.